# How to find and delete matching words in two different text files in VB?

Tags: vb.net

Its a wordy question, but basically I want to have VB check `textfile1` for matching words in `textfile2`, and then **delete** all instances of similar words in `textfile2` and output the results as `results.txt.`
Outputting results shouldn't be too difficult, but i'm unsure on where to proceed when it comes to recognizing similar wordage. Also, would it be possible to set up a whitelist (there's going to be one word repeated over and over - which I don't want deleted).

This is my open file / read file dialogue which I use for both prompts, and both are displayed visually in a textbox.

```
Sub Maplist()
    If txtFile.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(txtFile.FileName)
        tbx1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd
        sr.Close()
End If
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
A sample of the first text file looks like this:

> map_01, 200/250
>
> map_03, 358/450
>
> map_06, 528/2000

The second file looks like:

> map_01
>
> map_02
>
> map_03
>
> map_04
>
> map_05
>
> map_06

Basically the second file is the "master list'. I want the program to recognize a matching word between both files (for instance, the 01 in map_01) and then delete the entry from the master list. When I was talking about whitelisting I was concerned that it would match a word like"map" and delete everything in the master list. I didn't wanted it to delete the whole word just because it matched "map"

Comment: Please show us samples of the text files. Also, don't use `StreamReader` - there are better ways to read text files. But if you have to use a `StreamReader` then you **must** dispose of it when you're done.

Comment: talking about **whitelist**, do you want it to be single word which should not be replaced or can it be many words?

Comment: @Enigmativity Gave you an overview of what the files contain - - personal info is in each but it is formatted exactly the same.

Comment: @SubazSarma the only word that I don't want matched would. be "map" in this case so it doesn't cause problems. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make an array of words from both the `TextFile` and compare those. I did it for you here:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'make array of words from both the files
    Dim text1Array() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
    Dim text2Array() As String = TextBox2.Text.Split(" ")
    Dim NewText As String
    NewText = TextBox2.Text
    'loop through all the words in first array
    For i = 0 To text1Array.Length - 1
        'loop through all the words in second array
        For j = 0 To text2Array.Length - 1
            'match the words
            If text1Array(i) = text2Array(j) Then
                'replace the found word with an empty character
                NewText = NewText.Replace(text2Array(j), String.Empty)
                'delete double space 
                NewText = NewText.Replace("  ", " ")
            End If
        Next  
    Next
    'save it into third textbox
    TextBox3.Text = NewText
End Sub
```

I checked it like this:

```
Textbox1 contained :
```

> one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve

```
TextBox2 contained :
```

> one subaz three sarma five loves six coding eight ten all the twelve time

```
After clicking the button, TextBox3 contained:
```

> subaz sarma loves coding all the time

This works perfectly fine.

Now, about the whitelist, let's say you don't want to remove `"five"` even if it's matched. Do this:

```
Dim WhiteListWord As String = "five"
```

And change the condition as :

```
 If text1Array(i) = text2Array(j) And text1Array(i) <> WhiteListWord Then
```

New output in the `textbox3` will be :

> subaz sarma **five** loves coding all the time

Comment: One quick question -- my files are formatted a little different that is causing some errors..is it possible to make the program work looking like [this?](http://i.imgur.com/tHO0b1W.png) Im working on getting a way to clear everything past the comma in the second box as we speak, so just ignore that xD

Comment: sorry but I don't really understand what you're asking :DWhat's the problem with that?  Please explain what you exactly mean.

Comment: Basically the operation executes fine, but nothing is getting removed X_X. I think it might be because both files have an enter after each line because your answer works perfectly. [this video might help more then my noob explanation xD](http://i.imgur.com/P6Eiw19.gifv). Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Oh I get it. It's because the items in the list are like this : `surf_comer-T1`. But in the code I posted, the words are separated by a space, " ". Instead of  `Dim text1Array() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ")`, use `.Split("-")`

Comment: Still no luck i'm afraid :(. I can send you the files if you think it would help

Comment: Wait a minute. Let's say there's an item `surf_column` in list1 and there are two items in list2: `surf_column` and `surf_column_2`. Do you want to remove both or just `surf_column`? Because if you want to delete both, you can just use `ListBox1.Items().ToString.Contains("your text here")`.

Comment: In this case I would want only surf_column deleted. Think of it like every new line is a different word / map

Comment: is that a textbox or a listbox?

Comment: that is a textbox...a listbox would be a good idea though lol

Comment: well why don't you load those into a listbox and then split each item with `.Split("-")`

Comment: Will try when i get back. Thanks!